# O que faz o comando setCell no javascript

Tags: javascript, asp

Pelo nome dá a entender que esse comando configura uma célula em uma table/grid. Mas estou com dificuldades de entender a sua sintaxe misturada com `asp`.

```
<%If col_cod <> "" Then %>
    oGrid.setCell(<%=linha%>,'<%=col_cod%>',codigo);
<% End If %>

<%If col_nom <> "" Then %>
    oGrid.setCell(<%=linha%>,'<%=col_nom%>',descricao);
<% End If %>
```

Pelo visto ele popula a coluna `col_cod` com o valor de `codigo` e `col_nom` com o valor de `Descricao`, mas me complica o primeiro parâmetro, que no caso é o valor vindo do `asp` para `linha`. Então, o que ele faz exatamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método `.setCell` cria uma célula/coluna de uma tabela `<td></td>`.

O primeiro parâmetro representa o índice da coluna `ColumnIndex`.

O segundo parâmetro representa o índice da linha (row) `RowIndex`.

O terceiro parâmetro representa o conteúdo da coluna.

Note que essas funções e métodos não pertencem ao JavaScript. São providos de uma biblioteca escrito em JavaScript chamada "GridData".

http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/softimage2013/ja_jp/sdkguide/si_om/GridData.SetCell.html

Comment: Achei que fosse js, pela forma como foi escrita. Como eu estou fazendo a conversão de um código ASP para js, achei que fosse.